# why the elevator stuckes in a state?

Tags: vhdl

this is vhdl code for an elevator for 7 floors
the coding is encapsulated into 3 states s0=no move ,s1=move up , s2 =move down 
if it is in s0 it should wait for 2 cycles after that move up/down according to the desired floor or called floor on the next positive edge .
The problem is that the elevator is stuck in s1 state
could anyone help me please ?

```
-- Cad Project 
-- Project Name : Elevator 
-- Date : 18\12\2013


library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--Entity Decleration

entity Elevator is
  port (call, clk, press                : in     std_logic;
    -- Call To Call The Elevator ,press if a key is pressrd from the pannel inside the elevator . 
    Desire_floor, Call_Floor            : in     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    -- Desired_floor is the floor number choosed from inside the elevator .
    -- called_floor  is the floor number that the   "Call" Key has been pressed from . 
    weight                      : in     std_logic;
    Door_open_close, Move_up, move_down, OverWeight : out    std_logic;
    -- Door_open_close is 1 when opened ,0 when closed .
    -- OverWeight is 1 when the weight is over 500 KG.
    Current_Floor                   : buffer std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    temp1_state, temp2_state            : buffer std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7          : out    std_logic_vector (2 downto 0));
end;

--architecture Decleration  
architecture Elevator of Elevator is
  type   state is (s0, s1, s2);
  --s0 state represents no move ,s1 state represents  move up ,s2 state represents move down .
  signal current_state             : state             := s0;
  signal next_state            : state;
  signal Desired_floor, Called_Floor       : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal X                 : std_logic             := '0';  -- X is a signal used to restart the timer or to resume it's count.
  signal counter               : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);  -- Timer befor closing/opening the doors "timer".
  signal counter2              : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";  -- Timer for the elevator to move up or down.
  signal temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);


begin

  P1 : process (clk , weight, x)
    variable s11 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    -- Variable insted of the counter signal -->to have the direct assigment
  begin
    if (weight = '1') then
      OverWeight    <= '1';
      current_state <= s0;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
      if (x = '1') then     -- if X equals to 1 that means restart the timer. 
    s11 := "000";
      elsif (x = '0') then  -- if X equals 0 then count up "keep counting ".
    s11 := s11+1;
      end if;
      current_state <= next_state;
      counter       <= s11;
      OverWeight    <= '0';
    end if;
    counter <= s11;
    o5      <= counter;
  end process P1;

  P2 : process (clk)            -- this process if for the 2nd timer.
    variable s4 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    -- Variable insted of the counter2 signal -->to have the direct assigment
  begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
      if (press = '1') then
    Desired_floor <= Desire_floor;
    if (Current_Floor < Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 +1;
    elsif (Current_Floor > Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 -1;
    end if;
    counter2 <= s4;

      elsif (call = '1') then
    Called_Floor <= Call_Floor;
    if (Current_Floor < Called_Floor) then
      s4 := s4 +1;
    elsif (Current_Floor > Called_Floor) then
      s4 := s4 -1;
    end if;
      end if;
    end if;
    counter2 <= s4;
    o1       <= counter2;
    o2       <= Desired_floor;
    o3       <= Called_Floor;
    counter2 <= s4;
    --Desired_floor<=Desire_floor;
  end process P2;


  P3 : process (counter, current_state)
  begin
    case current_state is

      when s0 =>
    if(counter < "001") then
      x     <= '0';
      Current_Floor <= Current_Floor;
      next_state    <= s0;
      temp1_state   <= "00";
    else
      if (press = '1') then
        if(Desired_floor > Current_Floor) then
          next_state  <= s1;
          temp2_state <= "01";
        elsif (Desired_floor < Current_Floor) then
          next_state  <= s2;
          temp2_state <= "10";
        end if;
      else
        if (call = '1') then
          if (Called_Floor > Current_Floor) then
        next_state  <= s1;
        temp2_state <= "01";
          elsif (Called_Floor < Current_Floor) then
        next_state  <= s2;
        temp2_state <= "10";
          end if;
        end if;
      end if;
      x <= '1';
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '1';
    Move_up     <= '0';
    move_down   <= '0';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    temp1_state <= "00";

      when s1 =>
    temp1 <= (Desired_floor - Current_Floor);
    temp2 <= (Called_Floor-Current_Floor);
    o4    <= temp1;
    if ((temp1 /= "000") or (temp2 /= "000")) then
      next_state    <= s1;
      temp2_state   <= "01";
      Current_Floor <= counter2;
    elsif (((Desired_floor-Current_Floor) = "000")or ((Called_Floor-Current_Floor) = "000")) then
      next_state  <= s0;
      temp2_state <= "00";
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '0';
    Move_up     <= '1';
    move_down   <= '0';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    x       <= '1';
    temp1_state <= "01";

      when s2 =>
    temp3 <= (Current_Floor-Desired_floor);
    temp4 <= (Current_Floor-Called_Floor);
    if ((temp3 /= "000") or (temp4 /= "000")) then
      next_state    <= s2;
      temp2_state   <= "10";
      Current_Floor <= counter2;
    elsif (((Current_Floor-Desired_floor) = "000") or ((Called_Floor-Current_Floor) = "000")) then
      next_state  <= s0;
      temp2_state <= "00";
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '0';
    Move_up     <= '0';
    move_down   <= '1';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    x       <= '1';
    temp1_state <= "10";

    end case;
  end process P3;
end;


**********************************
```

I mad a lot of changes on the code and still have a problem .How can i save the value of an input at a certain state and ignore it's value until the next entering of the same state

```
-- Cad Project .
-- Project Name : Elevator .
-- Date : 18\12\2013.
-- Group Number : 13. 


library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--Entity Decleration

entity Elevator is
  port (clk, press                  : in     std_logic;
    -- Call To Call The Elevator ,press if a key is pressrd from the pannel inside the elevator . 
    Desire_floor                    : in     std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    -- Desired_floor is the floor number choosed from inside the elevator .
    -- called_floor  is the floor number that the   "Call" Key has been pressed from . 
    weight                      : in     std_logic;
    Door_open_close, Move_up, move_down, OverWeight : out    std_logic;
    -- Door_open_close is 1 when opened ,0 when closed .
    -- OverWeight is 1 when the weight is over 500 KG.
    Current_Floor                   : buffer std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    temp1_state, temp2_state            : buffer std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7          : out    std_logic_vector (2 downto 0));
end;

--architecture Decleration  
architecture Elevator of Elevator is
  type   state is (s0, s1, s2);
  --s0 state represents no move ,s1 state represents  move up ,s2 state represents move down .
  signal current_state             : state             := s0;
  signal next_state            : state;
  signal Desired_floor             : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal X                 : std_logic             := '0';  -- X is a signal used to restart the timer or to resume it's count.
  signal counter               : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);  -- Timer befor closing/opening the doors "timer".
  signal counter2              : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";  -- Timer for the elevator to move up or down.
  signal temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal temp6                 : std_logic;

begin

  P1 : process (clk , weight, x)
    variable s11 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    -- Variable insted of the counter signal -->to have the direct assigment
  begin
    if (weight = '1') then
      OverWeight    <= '1';
      current_state <= s0;
    elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
      if (x = '1') then     -- if X equals to 1 that means restart the timer. 
    s11 := "000";
      elsif (x = '0') then  -- if X equals 0 then count up "keep counting ".
    s11 := s11+1;
      end if;
      current_state <= next_state;
      counter       <= s11;
      OverWeight    <= '0';
    end if;
    counter <= s11;
    o5      <= counter;
  end process P1;

  P2 : process (clk)            -- this process if for the 2nd timer.
    variable s4 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
    -- Variable insted of the counter2 signal -->to have the direct assigment
  begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
      if (press = '1') then
    if (Current_Floor < Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 +1;
    elsif (Current_Floor > Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 -1;
    end if;
    counter2 <= s4;


      end if;
    end if;
    counter2 <= s4;
    o1       <= counter2;
    o2       <= Desired_floor;
    counter2 <= s4;
  end process P2;


  P3 : process (counter, current_state)
  begin
    case current_state is

      when s0 =>
    if(counter < "010") then
      x     <= '0';
      Current_Floor <= Current_Floor;
      next_state    <= s0;
      temp1_state   <= "00";
    else
      if (press = '1') then
        if(Desired_floor > Current_Floor) then
          next_state  <= s1;
          temp2_state <= "01";
        elsif (Desired_floor < Current_Floor) then
          next_state  <= s2;
          temp2_state <= "10";
        end if;

      end if;
      x <= '1';
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '1';
    Move_up     <= '0';
    move_down   <= '0';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    temp1_state <= "00";
    temp6       <= '1';

      when s1 =>
    temp1 <= (Desired_floor - Current_Floor);

    o4 <= temp1;
    if ((temp1 /= "000")) then
      next_state    <= s1;
      temp2_state   <= "01";
      Current_Floor <= counter2;
    elsif ((Desired_floor-Current_Floor) = "000") then
      next_state  <= s0;
      temp2_state <= "00";
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '0';
    Move_up     <= '1';
    move_down   <= '0';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    x       <= '1';
    temp1_state <= "01";
    temp6       <= '0';

      when s2 =>
    temp3 <= (Current_Floor-Desired_floor);

    if ((temp3 /= "000")) then
      next_state    <= s2;
      temp2_state   <= "10";
      Current_Floor <= counter2;
    elsif ((Current_Floor-Desired_floor) = "000") then
      next_state  <= s0;
      temp2_state <= "00";
    end if;
    Door_open_close <= '0';
    Move_up     <= '0';
    move_down   <= '1';
    Current_Floor   <= counter2;
    x       <= '1';
    temp1_state <= "10";
    temp6       <= '0';

    end case;
  end process P3;

  P4 : process (temp6, clk)
  begin
    if (clk 'event and clk = '1') then
      if (temp6'event and temp6 = '1')then
    --if ( current_state =s0 ) then 
    Desired_floor <= Desire_floor;
      else
    Desired_floor <= Desired_floor;
      end if;
      Desired_floor <= Desired_floor;
    end if;

  end process P4;
end;
```

Comment: You need to indent the code properly - otherwise people who know vhdl may not look at it

Comment: Read about single process versus 2-process state machines. After that, even if you decide to stick with the not so easy 2-process version, you may have picked up some ideas where the trouble might be.

Answer (score 0):

**It looks like the floor counter is only being incremented when the user presses 'press'.**

*Explanation*

If we're not on the desired floor yet, then `Current_Floor` is driven by `counter2`

```
temp1 <= (Desired_floor - Current_Floor);

o4 <= temp1;
if ((temp1 /= "000")) then
  next_state    <= s1;
  temp2_state   <= "01";
  Current_Floor <= counter2;
```

`counter2` is driven by `s4`:

```
 if (rising_edge(clk)) then
  if (press = '1') then
    if (Current_Floor < Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 +1;
    elsif (Current_Floor > Desired_floor) then
      s4 := s4 -1;
    end if;
    counter2 <= s4; <-
  end if;
end if;
counter2 <= s4; <-
o1       <= counter2;
o2       <= Desired_floor;
counter2 <= s4; <-
```

(Aside, why do you assign `s4` to `counter2` three times?)

`s4` is only changed when `press` is asserted. So your lift is only going to be moving up or down a floor when someone pushes the button.

*General comments*

Your process sensitivity lists are all over the place! Your sensitivity lists should either be `clock` or `clock,reset`. Asynchronous processes (those without a clock in the sensitivity list) do have their place, but I generally avoid them unless absolutely necessary. I find it a lot easier to visualise the timing behaviour in my head when everything is strictly synchronous.

```
P1 : process (clk , weight, x)         <- BAD
P2 : process (clk)                     <- GOOD
P3 : process (counter, current_state)  <- OKAY
P4 : process (temp6, clk)              <- BAD
```

Indenting has a huge impact on how you read the code. Learn to indent properly. I use the emacs VHDL mode, it has a great beautify function which really helps. I ran your code through it when I edited the comment and wrote this answer.

Your signal names need work. things like `temp` are a bad idea. you are doing pretty well with commenting though, so that's a plus. keep that up!

I'm going to briefly mention the code redundancy, example:

```
  if (temp6'event and temp6 = '1')then
--if ( current_state =s0 ) then 
    Desired_floor <= Desire_floor;
  else
    Desired_floor <= Desired_floor;
  end if;
  Desired_floor <= Desired_floor;
```

If it was different before, totally understandable, but clean that stuff up, unnecessary reading for whoever is on the receiving end of your code.